# React - auth won't work because of order of firing functions

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, authentication, react-router

Trying to do authentication with React. In my Login.js file I have my handleClick function that fetches json (used with session storage) and a submit button with a Link Container. Now in my index.js file I have a requireAuth function with replace. My issue is that the requireAuth function fires before my handleClick. How do I make it fire after my handleClick so that handleClick will check if the username and password is successful before logging the user in?? Right now it just won't push me through to the next page. Code samples are appreciated. I'm using React Router v3.

Login.js:

```
handleClick() {

    fetch('/backend/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        })
    })
    .then(response =>{
        if (response.ok) {
            response.json().then(data => {
                sessionStorage.setItem('loggedIn', data.success);
                console.log('login success: ' + sessionStorage.getItem('loggedIn'));
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('failed');
        }
    })  
}

render () {
  <LinkContainer to='/Dashboard'>
    <Button onClick={this.handleClick} type="submit"> Submit /> 
    </Button>
  </LinkContainer> 
}
```

index.js:

```
function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
if (!(sessionStorage.getItem('loggedIn') === true)) {
   console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('loggedIn'));
      replace({
        pathname: '/',
        state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
    });
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Container}>
        <IndexRoute component={Homepage}/>
        <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter=
{requireAuth}/>
   </Route> 
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<LinkContainer to='/Dashboard'>`, just have the button having the `onCLick` function.
When the response from login is success, use the react-router `push`, to send the user to the 'dashboard' route as below.

`import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
browserHistory.push('/some/path');`